# flexbox- I cant figure out what's causing this div to have a blocked out space in flexbox

Tags: html, css, web, flexbox

if anybody could help me solve what's causing this purple blocked-out box in my #header-content it would be greatly appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32EFJ.png)

```css
#header {
    background-color: #343c63;
    height: 400px;
   
}

.main-nav {
    display: flex;
    padding: 0px 100px 0px 100px;
    list-style: none;
}


.main-nav li:first-child {
    margin-right: auto;
}

.main-nav a {
    margin: 10px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#header-content {
   display: flex;
  
   padding-top: 100px;
   padding-left: 100px;
   padding-right: 100px;
}

#image-1 {
 margin-right: 100px;
  
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>top-flex-box</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    </head>
   
    <body>
        
        <div id="header">
        <nav>
            <ul class="main-nav">
                <li><a href="#" class="logo">Header Logo</a></li>
                
                <li><a href="#">Link One</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link Two</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link Three</a></li>
                
            </ul>
        </nav>
            
            <div id="header-content">
                <div>
                <h1>This website is awesome</h1>
                <p>This website has some subtext that goes here under the main title. It's smaller font and the color is lower contrast.</p>
                </div>
                
                <div id='image-1'>
                    <p>this is a placeholder for an image</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
        
        
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: Please don't add junk text to get around the words/code limit in the question wizard. Instead, find something *useful* to say about the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Edited]

Purple blocked-out box are default flex-box behaviour, which prevents flex-boxes of becoming smaller than it's contents.

it can solved by:

1 .You remove purple blocked-out box by use inline-block

> ```
> #header-content {
>      display: inline-flex;
>      padding-top: 100px;
>      padding-left: 100px;
>      padding-right: 100px;
>   }
> ```

The `display:inline-flex` does not make flex items display inline. It makes the flex container display inline. The main difference between `display: flex` and `display: inline-flex` is that `display: inline-flex` will make the flex container an inline element while its content maintains its flexbox properties.

2. Removed it by giving full properties to control to child's eg:

> ```
> #header-content {
>   display: flex;
>   padding-top: 100px;
>   padding-left: 100px;
>   padding-right: 100px;
> }
>     
> #image-1 {
>   width: 50vw;
>   margin-right: 100px;
> }
> ```

3. Control the purple blocked-out box using [justify-content](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_justify-content.asp) properties

> ```
>   #header-content {
>     display: flex;
>     justify-content: space-between;
>     padding-top: 100px;
>     padding-left: 100px;
>     padding-right: 100px;
>   }
> ```